# PHP error message on form after enabling intl.so extension

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony, intl

[image: I've attached an image of the error message I am getting. At first my date drop down select for users birthday was working fine. But I finally installed and enabled the intl extension that symfony2 was asking for and now I get that error message. Any idea what the problem could be?]

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace Home\JoinBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Home\JoinBundle\Entity\User;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->fname;
        $user->lname;
        $user->bday;

         $form = $this->get('form.factory')
                 ->createBuilder('form', $user)
                 ->add('fname', 'text', array('label' => 'First Name: '))
                 ->add('lname', 'text', array('label' => 'Last Name: '))
                 ->add('bday', 'birthday',  array('input' => 'array', 'widget' => 'choice'))
                 ->getForm();


        return $this->render('HomeJoinBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that the default value isn't working, but try this out (doing the same thing it should be doing by default as detailed in http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html

```
$dater = new \IntlDateFormatter();
$form = $this->get('form.factory')
             ->createBuilder('form', $user)
             ->add('fname', 'text', array('label' => 'First Name: '))
             ->add('lname', 'text', array('label' => 'Last Name: '))
             ->add('bday', 'birthday',  array('input' => 'array', 'widget' => 'choice', 'months' => $dater))
             ->getForm();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for response. I tried what you suggested and I get this message: ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Home\JoinBundle\Controller\IntlDateFormatter' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/src/Home/JoinBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php on line 21

Comment: Fatal Error should be fixed now.  I missed the \ in front of IntlDateFormatter, see the ref above.

Comment: I get an error saying "The option "month" does not exist " so I changed it to months and I get a fatal error again. Could this be something to do with my compiled intl failing tests? I ran a make test after I compiled it but it failed some tests. Symfony stopped asking me to install and enable the extension so I thought everything was fine.

Comment: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\MonthChoiceList::__construct() must be an instance of IntlDateFormatter, null given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php on line 53 and defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/MonthChoiceList.php line 24

Comment: I just edited the code, if that doesn't work, I'll see if I can replicate error on my local machine.